# GUI performance (speed) in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, user-interface, animation

I am currently developing a GUI in Python with a focus on function that is supposed to show wipe animation of Image A covering Image B in square frame.

While there are no syntax errors in my snippet of code, I encounter a couple of performance issues.

Firstly, with regards to the velocity of image transitions. If I set the first parameter of "after" method to the minimum integer value of 1, transition still seems a bit slow.

```
def wipe():
        ImageA_Width, ImageA_Height = img.size
        data_A_norm = asarray(img2)
        data_B_norm = asarray(img)

        def get_frame(frame_number):
            frame = np.ones((ImageA_Width, ImageA_Height, 3))
            for x in range(0, ImageA_Width):
                for y in range(0, ImageA_Height):
                    if x < frame_number: 
                        frame[y,x] = data_A_norm[y,x]
                    else:
                        frame[y,x] = data_B_norm[y,x]
            return frame
        
       def show_frame(frame_number):
           global shot, label3
           if frame_number < ImageA_Width+1:
              frame = get_frame(frame_number)
              image_opened = Image.fromarray(frame.astype(np.uint8))
              shot = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image_opened)
              label3 = Label(window, image=shot)
              label3.place(x=800, y=200)
              label3.after(1, show_frame, frame_number+1)
        
      show_frame(0)
```

I have figured out that the time spent on animations could be reduced if images are stored in a list instead of being stored in a variable in each iteration.

Will this approach really improve my performance? If so, how this could be achieved in Python?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def wipe():
    # Load the images into numpy arrays
    data_A_norm = np.asarray(img2)
    data_B_norm = np.asarray(img)

    # Get the size of the images
    image_width, image_height = img.size

    def get_frame(frame_number):
        # Create an empty frame
        frame = np.ones((image_width, image_height, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

        # Use a mask to select which pixels should come from each image
        mask = np.arange(image_width) < frame_number
        frame[:,:,0] = data_A_norm[:,:,0] * mask + data_B_norm[:,:,0] * (1 - mask)
        frame[:,:,1] = data_A_norm[:,:,1] * mask + data_B_norm[:,:,1] * (1 - mask)
        frame[:,:,2] = data_A_norm[:,:,2] * mask + data_B_norm[:,:,2] * (1 - mask)

        return frame
        
    def show_frame(frame_number):
        global shot, label3
        if frame_number < image_width + 1:
            # Get the next frame and display it
            frame = get_frame(frame_number)
            image_opened = Image.fromarray(frame)
            shot = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image_opened)
            label3 = Label(window, image=shot)
            label3.place(x=800, y=200)

            # Call this function again after a delay
            label3.after(50, show_frame, frame_number + 1)
    
    # Start the animation
    show_frame(0)
```

This version of the code has a few changes:

The get_frame function uses numpy's vectorized operations to select which pixels should come from each image, which should be much faster than using nested for loops.

The show_frame function is called at a slower rate, using a delay of 50 milliseconds instead of 1 millisecond. This should allow the get_frame function to keep up with the frame rate.

The Image.fromarray function is used to convert the numpy array back into a PIL image, which should be faster than using the Image and ImageTk libraries separately.

Comment: Thanks! But is it possible to achieve the same result using list of images and for loops?